# No puedo migrar seeders de mis tablas, obtengo el error Integrity constraint violation: 1452

Tags: mysql, laravel

Al realizar la migracion de mis --seeders obtengo el siguiente error "Integrity constraint violation: 1452". Ademas esto solo sucede cuando trato de migrar mis --seeders porque la creacion de mis tablas se llevan a cabo con normalidad. Adjunto del mensanje de error, la creacion de mi tabla operadores y el DatabaseSeeder que ejecuto.

- Mensaje de error

```
 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sistema-mpv`.`operators`, CONSTRAINT `operators_organic_unit_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`organic_unit_id`) REFERENCES `organic_units` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL) (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `operators` (`name`, `last_name`, `email`, `password`, `organic_unit_id`, `rol_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Administrador, Admin, admin@gmail.com, $2y$10$GpeJiJla0IS1bIDfWqnUv.vnqa7TabU.9Uki7ArdysB1GDYiEU50W, 1, 1, 2023-10-11 11:17:37, 2023-10-11 11:17:37))
```

- Migracion de la llave foranea

```php
    Schema::create('operators', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->string('name');
                $table->string('last_name');
                $table->string('email')->unique();
                $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
                $table->string('password');
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('organic_unit_id')->nullable();
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('rol_id');
                $table->rememberToken();
                $table->timestamps();
                $table->foreign('organic_unit_id')->references('id')->on('organic_units')->onDelete('set null');
            });
```

```php
public function run(): void
    {
        $this->call(OperatorSeeder::class);
        $this->call(RoleSeeder::class);
        $this->call(OrganicUnitSeeder::class);
    }
```

Comment: Este error normalmente indica que el valor que has puesto en el campo de la foreign key (organic_unit_id) no existe en la tabla operators. Por las imágenes entiendo que en esta tabla no debe existir el registro con ID 1.

Comment: El código y los mensajes de error siempre _como texto, con formato_. [No todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: una llave foránea jamas puede ser null, por eso el problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

por si a alguien le sirve la solución fue bastante simple, era acomodar el orden en que se migraban los seeders, comenzando por las tablas(organic_units y roles) que están relacionadas a través de una foreign key en la tabla principal (operators). El código solución es:

```php
public function run(): void
    {
        $this->call(OrganicUnitSeeder::class);
        $this->call(RoleSeeder::class);
        $this->call(OperatorSeeder::class);
        $this->call(DocumentTypeSeeder::class);
    }
```